# How to load a navigation view created programmatically and make it a ModalView?

Tags: iphone, view, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog, xib

I'm  making an iphone app out of the utility template in xcode. So in my FlispSideView I have a button that should show a custom image picker. I decided to use this nice one here [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker).

Now I made some changes cuz I'm not using a navigation controller to load the custom image picker (but rather modally) which is created programmatically inside the .m file. So I made the FlipSideView the delegate for the custom image picker but still lost when I come to loading the view. I created a xib file and tried to connect it to the image picker but that didn't work. 
So I wonder what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I interpreted your question correctly, but based on the title, I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
// Initialize your custom controller and set the delegate
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
controller.delegate = self;

// Set the title of your custom controller (optional)
controller.title = NSLocalizedString(@"My View", nil);

// Create a navigation controller with your custom controller as the root view controller
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

// Present the navigation controller as a modal view controller
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navCon animated:YES];

// Release objects you own
[navCon release];
[controller release];
```

If your image picker is a controller, and all the outlets on your xib are properly connected to it, this should work. You should be able to make your FlipSideView the delegate. Pressing cancel or done in the modal view should call a message in the delegate that says

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

EDIT:

Here is the first line of my example code updated to match the tutorial you are using:

```
CustomImagePicker *controller = [[CustomImagePicker alloc] init];
```

The rest is the same. You initialize a navigation controller with `controller` as the root view controller, then present the navigation controller as a modal view controller.

Comment: Thanx Katfish. Could you please take a look at the link I provided? Sorry it wasn't a link until I edited it. Are you saying I should make a xib file? cuz in the link I provided they guy who made the (custom image picker) didn't have a xib file for the image picker view. He created it programmatically. So I think I have to change so many things to create the same view he created and make it a modal view (call it and dismiss it from it parent which is the FlipsideView in this case)

Comment: The class created in the tutorial does not have a xib, so all you would need to change in my code is the line where I initialize the controller. I will update my answer to reflect the tutorial.

Comment: Thanx again Katfish. I tried and it doesn't load anything when I click the button. I'm sure the button is connected to the action method. I wonder if it's ok for a scrollView to be a view contreoller? Here is the 1st line of the CustomImagePicker.m after the viewDidLoad: `// Create view
 UIScrollView *view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`

Comment: When you say it does not load anything, do you mean nothing happens at all? If you put a breakpoint in your action method, can you determine what is going wrong?

Comment: I did put a breakpoint at the start of the Button action method. And stepped into it line by line but nothing happens I guess. Isn't supposed to jump to the CustomImagePicker.m when it reaches this line`[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navCon animated:YES];`

Comment: On a side note, I was able to run this CustomIMagePicker project when I downloadded it the 1st time. Now it too doesn't run well. It shows an empty view instead of the image picker it's supposed to. I thought maybe I changed some file do I extracted the downloaded zip file again and tried to run it without any success. Btw I can send you my FlipSideview.h,m,xib and also the CustomImagePicker.h,m files if you like. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I just realized that my code is wrong for your application. Since you are not using a navigation based application, you do not want to say self.navigationController. Instead, just say self.

Comment: Thanks Katfish. It loads the view now but still empty view. the Cancel button works ok too. As I said in my side note above, even the original open source project doesn't work now even though I downloaded it again and tried to tun it. It loads an empty image picker view and even its Cancel button doesn't work. Really weird it worked before. I didn't upgrade my SDK or Xcode or anything. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Got it working fully now. Actually this line is not needed `CustomImagePicker *controller = [[CustomImagePicker alloc] init];` cuz there is already an instance created in the (mainViewController) in the open source project or in (FlipSideView) in my project called _imagePicker. So here follow the answer code with proper modifications.

Comment: `- (IBAction)showImagePicker:(id)sender{
    // Initialize your custom controller and set the delegate
     _imagePicker.delegate = self;
    //controller.title = NSLocalizedString(@"My View", nil);
    // Create a navigation controller with your custom controller as the root view controller
    UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_imagePicker];
    // Present the navigation controller as a modal view controller
    [self presentModalViewController:navCon animated:YES];
    // Release objects you own
    [navCon release];`

Answer (score 0):

Creating navigation programatically
Use the code below to navigate programatically. Write the following code in
**AppDelegate.m** class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    [_window addSubview:nav.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
  }
```